# Is it faster to create new instance of class/variable or set existing one?

Tags: python

In Python 2.7, (or in programming languages in general), is it faster to create a new instance of a class/variable or to set an existing one to something new?

For example, which is faster to create `another_pic.png`? This:

```
my_img = Image.open(cur_directory_path + '\\my_pic.png') # don't need this anymore
new_img = Image.open(cur_directory_path + '\\another_pic.png') # but need this new pic
```

or this:

```
my_img = Image.open(cur_directory_path + '\\my_pic.png') # don't need this anymore
my_img = Image.open(cur_directory_path + '\\another_pic.png') # but need this new pic
```

I ask because I have one Image variable which I "gets around" so to speak in my code, by constantly being reset to various things, and I am wondering if this affects performance at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, you're creating two completely new objects at the exact same speed, so to that end I don't think either one is faster than the other. You're never really "resetting" an object; you're just reassigning a name. All that's happening is you're changing an existing pointer to a new memory location, which is a fraction of a fraction of a second.

The main difference is that with the bottom option, you have left an unused object for the garbage collector to pick up, but deallocating memory is not a very speed-intensive task. It's possible (depending on the number of free objects you have lying around) that won't even happen before your program ends. But you're also using more memory by keeping two objects lying around. So if you're constantly importing new images, to the degree that it may impact your memory, it's probably best to be resetting the same pointer. Or you could even invoke the garbage collector manually if you're concerned about running out of memory, but it doesn't sound like you are.

Answer (score 1):

They're exactly the same. Both go through the process of importing the image. The variable assignment is only storing a reference to the object. The only difference is that the latter may begin garbage collecting the `my_pic.png` image sooner since there are no more references to the object.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is faster to reuse variables as long as they are storing objects of the same type then it is to constantly create a new one. This boils down to addressing in memory and the fact that if you already have a variable (an address in memory is associated with it) then it will be easy to access that slot in memory and update the object located there. The reason that I mention that the object types should be the same is because of how memory is allocated for classes and objects when they are created at run time. As for why creating a new variable to store objects is slower is because it has to find proper space in memory (enough free space for the object) and then assign that address to that variable. This involves accessing address lookup tables and depending on the table configuration would also add time. The thing is the difference is so small that in any normal application you shouldn't notice it.